# Using transform translate to create a 3d affect

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, translate

I am not able to use `transform: translateZ` to change the position of back div to create a 3d affect . There are no changes at all in the image. I have used perspective and perspective origin to try and create a 3d affect. The front and back div are respectively the front and back sides of a cube. Here is the below code written in css and html respectively

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube-container {
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.front {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(62, 86, 226);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.back {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(62, 86, 226);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -100vh;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(100px)
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on `.cube` and I would also use `position: absolute;` for `.front`. I dont understand the perspective perfectly, but its common to use higher numbers like: `perspective: 500px;`.

Hope it helped! :)

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube-container {
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transform: rotateY(20deg);

}

.front {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```